# How can I increase the JSON deserialization MaxDepth limit in my ASP.NET Core webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.1

We're using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with .NET Framework 4.6.2.

We have a customer who needs to send up a rather largely nested json structure to our webapp.

When they make this call, we're outputting the following log and returning an error:

> The reader's MaxDepth of 32 has been exceeded. Path '*super.long.path.to property*', line 1, position 42111."

I've looked through the ASP.NET Core codebase, and have observed a couple of references to `MaxDepth = 32` in the deserializer provided with the framework.

Is it possible to configure this to a different depth?

Comment: To those coming to this question at a later date - other users have added answers below for ASP.NET Core 3.1 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 where the exact configuration call has changed as the framework has been updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not tested this, but in Startup.cs you should be able to do something like this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 64;  // or however deep you need
});
```

Comment: As simple as that. It's worth highlighting that if you change this, there are other implications for your app - if you use a different serializer elsewhere to serialize (or have other entry points where deserialization can occur), you will also need to make this change to the settings in those serializers

Comment: Can make this setting for only one class. I want to limit the depth of only a certain class.

Comment: For me, I added this code and it worked.
 services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
 {
    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 64;  // or however deep you need
 });

Comment: When using AddControllers(), then services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 64):

Answer (score 3):

You could also set depth you need directly in deserialization as shown in the following example:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< T >(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MaxDepth = //the value you need
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET Core 3.1, try this in your startup.cs file. Make sure to install the Newtonsoft.Json package.

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 64;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Core 5.0 with `System.Text.Json`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => 
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 64;
});
```