# How to set Max Depth for specific class in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I need to have a Model as below and I need Category.MySegments to have a MaxDepth of 3. Instead of specifying a MaxDepth setting on an application-level or controller level, I need it for only this class.
How to do that?

```
public class Category
{
    .
    .
    public List<Segment> MySegments{ get; set; }
    .
    .
}

public class Segment
{
    public string SegmentName { get; set; }
    public string GroupBy { get; set; }
    public List<Segment> InnerSegments { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a read-only field in Category Class

Comment: I want users to add until MaxDepth of 3. And I receive this as a request body in the controller.

Comment: Then you need to have a property in the class and assign the value to it from user input and then use it to populate the child objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could validate the model using a recursive approach like this:

```
private bool ExceedsDepth(Segment segment, int depth)
{
    if (depth == 1)
    {
        // max valid depth reached - return true if childs present, otherwise false
        return segment.InnerSegments != null && (segment.InnerSegments == null || segment.InnerSegments.Any());
    }

    // max depth not yet reached
    if (segment.InnerSegments == null ||
        segment.InnerSegments != null && !segment.InnerSegments.Any())
    {
        // element at depth has no child segments
        return false;
    }

    return segment.InnerSegments.Any(x=> ExceedsDepth(x, depth-1));
}
```

Usage in the validator:

```
var exceeded = mySegments.Any(x => ExceedsDepth(x, 3));
```

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if I got you right. Do you want to only accept requests with a maxDepth of 3 or do you want to accept every request and "cut off" the deeper nested segments afterwards?

**UPDATE**: Cut them afterwards with:

```
private Segment CutAtDepth(Segment segment, int depth)
{
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        // max valid depth reached
        if (segment.InnerSegments != null && segment.InnerSegments.Any())
        {
            // element at max depth has child segments
            segment.InnerSegments.Clear();
        }

        return segment;
    }

    segment.InnerSegments = segment.InnerSegments.Select(x=> CutAtDepth(x, depth - 1)).ToList();
    return segment;
}
```

Usage:

```
var limitedDepthObj = mySegments.Select(x=> CutAtDepth(x, 3));
```

Comment: I want to accept every request and "cut off" the deeper nested segments afterward.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now you have both options.

Comment: I Could do this, Since [MaxDepth has a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138212/how-can-i-increase-the-json-deserialization-maxdepth-limit-in-my-asp-net-core-we) I don't have to worry about a large nested request. I was worried about performance and this should be fine.